# Jquery Globalization reverse algorithm

Tags: jquery, jquery-globalization

Jquery Globalization works great.

You can format a currency doing something like this:

```
$("#currencyInput").val(Globalize.format(100000.25, "c"));
```

Is possible to reverse the formatting to be able to edit the value back? (keeping the culture format)

```
$("#currencyInput").val(Globalize.reverseFormat("$100,000.25", "c"));// 100000.25
```

Answer (score 0):

The Globalize plugin provides `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` methods that you can use:

```
$("#currencyInput").val(Globalize.parseFloat("$100,000.25", 10, "c"));
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but it converts the value back to javascript language, and it doesn't support culture anymore. For example, in "ro (Romanian)" culture, 10000.25 == 10.000,25  and if i Globalize.parseFloat("10.000,25") it returns 10000.25 instead of 10000,25

Comment: Sorry i am new to stackoverflow and i didn't knew that "Entery" key submits the form:)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `parseFloat()` returns a number, not a string, so it does not make sense for the returned value to use anything other than the language's decimal separator (`.`).

Comment: On a text input, i have the value "100.000,25 lei" (Globalize.format(100000.25, "c"). When user focuses on that input, i want to allow him to edit the value, but remove the currency symbol --- the new value should be "100000,25", which respects the culture's currency format. This is just for displaying purposes. Something like this probably: [link](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/globalization/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

A really old question, I know, but the to remove the currency symbol and keep culture formatting:

Parse the currency-formatted string value to a number using Globalize.parseFloat, as described above.

Take that value and format it as a culture-specific ***number*** string, not currency, using Globalize.format again, but with the "n" parameter, indicating you want a number:

```
   var x = Globalize.format(100000.25, "c")
   x = Globalize.parseFloat(x)
   x = Globalize.format(x, "n")
```